# autoit - how to execute a downloaded file?

Tags: autoit

So I'm trying to setup a script that executes a file that is downloaded from a URL.

At the moment, I have this code, which will just launch default browser, then access the URL typed into an input box (which then results in the download starting).

```
$inputBox = GUICtrlRead($downloadsURL)
ShellExecute($inputBox)
```

The file is currently being downloaded to the current logged in users "Downloads" directory (Windows Box).

What would be a "robust" solution for executing the downloaded file?

The filename changes often... would there be a way to rename the downloaded file?

Or maybe ensure I have a "clean" Downloads directory first, then have autoit automatically execute whatever file is in the directory after running the script?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should always clean up your original download files.  Leaving wasted space isn't fare to the end user.
2. You haven't really given us much to go on.  GUICtrlRead simply means you're reading a control (I assume an Input box).  And if that's the URL, then I would suggest using InetGet() to download the file to a specific place, then use Run or ShellExecute to run the file (if that's the kind of file that needs to be run that way).

So it might look this way:

```
Global $gszDir = @DocumentsCommonDir
Global $gszFileName = "mydownloadfile.exe"
Global $gszURL = "URL To File To Download"

_DownloadAndRemoveOriginal($gszURL, $gszDir, $gszFileName)
If @error Then
    MsgBox(16 + 262144, "Error", "Error downloading: " & @error)
    Exit 1
EndIf

Func _DownloadAndRemoveOriginal($szURL, $szDirectory, $szFileName)

    ; remove old downloaded file
    Local $szFullPath = $szDirectory & "\" & $szFileName
    If FileExists($szFullPath) Then
        FileDelete($szFullPath)
    EndIf

    ; download and wait for download to complete
    Local $iGet = InetGet($szURL, $szFullPath, 1, 0)
    If Not $iGet Then
        ; failed
        Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    Local $iRet = ShellExecute($szFullPath)
    Return SetError(0, 0, $iRet)
EndFunc
```